# how to dynamically get center point of view group layout?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

This's my code

```
var graphHeight =  parentLayout.height
var graphPointView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_graph_point, null, false)
graphPointView.y =(graphHeight / 2f)
graphView.addView(graphPointView)
```

and...

[image]

The grey line is on the center position in the view group layout, why the red point is't on the center of view group layout? I want to make that on the center position. (like grey line)

What's the problem with my code?

view_graph_point.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/graph_point_view"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/graph_round_point"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

graph_round_point.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="#A04000"/>
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#fff" />
<size android:width="12dp" android:height="12dp"/>
```

Comment: Show your `R.layout.view_graph_point` xml

Comment: I added. @HongDuan

Comment: is `graph_round_point` png or shape drawable, if shape then do post the code. Also try to use wrap_content on height and width.

Comment: and the `@drawable/graph_round_point`?

Comment: I changed height and width to wrap_content . but graph point is still below the grey line. T.T.....check please graph_round_point.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's the problem with my code

It's most likely "problem" with your layout, not the code. I guess your container is not stretched to max width. Just ensure its width is `match_parent` not `wrap_content` and that should be it.